# Demonstrate divergence and rotational.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, electromagnetism

Show that
$$DIV(A)=\lim_{\Delta s\rightarrow0}\frac{\displaystyle\int\int_{\Delta v}A\cdot nds}{\Delta v}$$and,
$$ROT(A)\cdot n=\lim_{\Delta s\rightarrow 0}\frac{\displaystyle\oint_{C}A\cdot dr}{\Delta s}$$
Is there a demonstration for these results? One suggestion they gave me is to use the mean value theorem for integrals.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to put $\Delta v\to 0$ in the first case and say/understand what specifically you're integrating over in both cases. You're computing the divergence and the curl (rot) at a fixed point. How does it figure in? And of course you'll need to use Gauss's (the divergence) Theorem and Stokes's Theorem, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> The equations 
>   $$
> DIV(A)=\lim_{\Delta s\rightarrow0}\frac{\displaystyle\int\int_{\Delta v}A\cdot nds}{\Delta v}$$and
>   $$ROT(A)\cdot n=\lim_{\Delta s\rightarrow 0}\frac{\displaystyle\oint_{C}A\cdot dr}{\Delta s}$$

are NOT consequences of the ordinary definition of the divergence and rotational of a vector field: they are more general since they require only the *integrability of the vector field $A$* and no differentiability nor continuity conditions. Thus the standard definition of those vector operators follows easily from them, since considering

$$DIV(A)=\dfrac{\partial A_x}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial A_y}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial z} \tag1$$

$$ROT(A)= \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{\vec i}&{\vec j}&{\vec k}\\{\displaystyle \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}}&{\displaystyle \frac{\partial }{{\partial y}}}&{\displaystyle \frac{\partial }{{\partial z}}}\\A_x&A_y&A_z\end{array}} \right|\tag2$$

1. If you use [Gauss divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), $(1)$ can be shown easily. Try this yourself.
2. If you use [Stokes curl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), $(2)$ can be shown easily. Try this also yourself.